# Why won't VectorPlot yield a result? *Empty Graph*

Tags: vector, field, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to analyze vector fields through Mathematica however this specific R^2 to R^2 scenario yields nothing.  Given the picture, can any of you find what causes an issue with Mathematica's limits?
Bad code:
VectorPlot[{(y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]), (x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])}, {x, -3,
3}, {y, -3, 3}]

[Issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa0Ld.png)

What it should look like: [2D Vector Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFY4D.png)

Comment: Mathematica is INTENSELY case sensitive. It has never seen a function called sqrt. But it does know all about a function called Sqrt. That should do it

Comment: `VectorPlot[{y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you!  Mathematica didn't correct the input of sqrt(), but when the function was corrected to
VectorPlot[{(y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]), (x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}]
the proper graphic was produced.